# How do I trigger a jQuery function with a c# Calendar SelectedDateChange?

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a c# calendar control that triggers a form submission when the date changes. It is all set up and works fine (so I don't want to switch to the JQuery date-picker).

At the moment the form submits and redirects to a confirmation page. However, I want to change this so it pops up a Jquery UI dialog (or equivalent) with some Ts and Cs that the user has to agree to (with a checkbox) before they can submit the form.

I assume the simplest way to do this is to have a div with the Ts and Cs, checkbox and submit button in a hidden div that the thickbox shows. Question is, how do I trigger the dialog from the c# date change?

Been requested to add some code - trouble is, I don't know what to add!

If I was doing this with a button click, I'd put something like:

```
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) { 
          //...
     }
```

But how do I do the equivalent to pick it up from a SelectedDateChange event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)** for registering a script at run-time.

What you need is something like below in SelectedDateChange event code in c#:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), this.ClientID, "JavaScriptmethod()", true);
```

Replace JavaScriptmethod() with your javascript method or you can also write js in here too. This will execute the javascript method on SelectedDateChange event of C# calendar.